# disable radio input passed time button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable todays passed time.

For example:
if time 11:00 and 11:15 are passed then these button are not suppose to
be clickable.

Times input buttons are as follow:

11:00    11:15    11:30    11:45
12:00    12:15    12:30    12:45
13:00    13:15    13:30    13:45

19:00    19:15    19:30    19:45
20:00    20:15    20:30    20:45
21:00    21:15    21:30    21:45

I think I need to improve this check to disabled the input time buttons.

```
if ( c_hour >= o_hour && ( (c_minutes >= 15 ) ) ) {                         
 option.prop('disabled', true);
```

Note:
o_hour - clicked button hour
o_minutes - clicked button minute

My function

```
function updateTimeWindow(type) {
    let today = new Date();
    let c_hour = today.getUTCHours();
    let c_minutes = today.getUTCMinutes();
    let next_hour = c_hour;

    // $('#time_selector option').each(function () {
    $("input[name='time_selector']").each(function () {

        var option = $(this);
        var o_hour = $(this).attr('data-hour');
        var o_minutes = $(this).attr('data-minute');
        let current_element_id = option.attr('id')

        if (type == 1) { // today

            // disable passed time.
            // if (o_hour <= c_hour || (o_hour <= next_hour && o_minutes <= c_minutes)) {
            if ( c_hour >= o_hour && ( (c_minutes >= 15 ) ) ) {
                    option.prop('disabled', true);
                    $('label[class="'+current_element_id+'"]').addClass('no-drop');

            }

        } else if (type == 2) { // tommorrow.
            // enable all time.
            option.prop('disabled', false);
            $('label[class="' + current_element_id + ' no-drop"]').attr('class', current_element_id);
        }
    });
}
```

Time input radio are having following times

html

```
<div class="tab" style="display: block;">
  <div class="row new-rcb ">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
      <h5>Time</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center mb-2">
      <h3>Midday</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">



        <input type="radio" id="tt1" name="time_selector" value="11:00" data-hour="11" data-minute="00" disabled="">
        <label class="tt1 no-drop" for="tt1" style="justify-content: center;">11:00</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt2" name="time_selector" value="11:15" data-hour="11" data-minute="15" disabled="">
        <label class="tt2 no-drop" for="tt2" style="justify-content: center;">11:15 </label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt3" name="time_selector" value="11:30" data-hour="11" data-minute="30" disabled="">
        <label class="tt3 no-drop" for="tt3" style="justify-content: center;">11:30</label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt4" name="time_selector" value="11:45" data-hour="11" data-minute="45" disabled="">
        <label class="tt4 no-drop" for="tt4" style="justify-content: center;">11:45</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt5" name="time_selector" value="12:00" data-hour="12" data-minute="00" disabled="">
        <label class="tt5 no-drop" for="tt5" style="justify-content: center;">12:00</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt6" name="time_selector" value="12:15" data-hour="12" data-minute="15" disabled="">
        <label class="tt6 no-drop" for="tt6" style="justify-content: center;">12:15</label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt7" name="time_selector" value="12:30" data-hour="12" data-minute="30" disabled="">
        <label class="tt7 no-drop" for="tt7" style="justify-content: center;">12:30</label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="tt8" name="time_selector" value="12:45" data-hour="12" data-minute="45" disabled="">
        <label class="tt8 no-drop" for="tt8" style="justify-content: center;">12:45</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt9" name="time_selector" value="13:00" data-hour="13" data-minute="00" disabled="">
        <label class="tt9 no-drop" for="tt9" style="justify-content: center;">13:00</label>




      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt10" name="time_selector" value="13:15" data-hour="13" data-minute="15" disabled="">
        <label class="tt10 no-drop" for="tt10" style="justify-content: center;">13:15</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="tt11" name="time_selector" value="13:30" data-hour="13" data-minute="30" disabled="">
        <label class="tt11 no-drop" for="tt11" style="justify-content: center;">13:30</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="tt12" name="time_selector" value="13:45" data-hour="13" data-minute="45">
        <label class="tt12" for="tt12" style="justify-content: center;">13:45</label>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row new-rcb ">
    <div class="col-12 text-center mb-2 mt-2">
      <h3>Evening</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="t21" name="time_selector" value="19:00" data-hour="19" data-minute="00">
        <label class="t21" for="t21" style="justify-content: center;">19:00</label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="t22" name="time_selector" value="19:15" data-hour="19" data-minute="15">
        <label class="t22" for="t22" style="justify-content: center;">19:15</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="t23" name="time_selector" value="19:30" data-hour="19" data-minute="30">
        <label class="t23" for="t23" style="justify-content: center;">19:30</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="t24" name="time_selector" value="19:45" data-hour="19" data-minute="45">
        <label class="t24" for="t24" style="justify-content: center;">19:45</label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="t25" name="time_selector" value="20:00" data-hour="20" data-minute="00">
        <label class="t25" for="t25" style="justify-content: center;">20:00</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="t26" name="time_selector" value="20:15" data-hour="20" data-minute="15">
        <label class="t26" for="t26" style="justify-content: center;">20:15</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="t27" name="time_selector" value="20:30" data-hour="20" data-minute="30">
        <label class="t27" for="t27" style="justify-content: center;">20:30</label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="t28" name="time_selector" value="20:45" data-hour="20" data-minute="45">
        <label class="t28" for="t28" style="justify-content: center;">20:45</label>



      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="t29" name="time_selector" value="21:00" data-hour="21" data-minute="00">
        <label class="t29" for="t29" style="justify-content: center;">21:00</label>




      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">

        <input type="radio" id="t210" name="time_selector" value="21:15" data-hour="21" data-minute="15">
        <label class="t210" for="t210" style="justify-content: center;">21:15</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="t211" name="time_selector" value="21:30" data-hour="21" data-minute="30">
        <label class="t211" for="t211" style="justify-content: center;">21:30</label>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="t212" name="time_selector" value="21:45" data-hour="21" data-minute="45">
        <label class="t212" for="t212" style="justify-content: center;">21:45</label>





      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo html added please take a look.

Comment: @MisterJojo Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta

Comment: @MisterJojo tt1 t212 just using these classes to disabled or enable it.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part is to simplify ...

```js
const
  myform = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, timSelects_Rbuttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="time_selector"]')
  ; 

updateTimeWindow(1)  



function updateTimeWindow(type)
  {
  let today       = new Date();
  let c_HourMinut = (today.getUTCHours() * 60) + today.getUTCMinutes();

  if (type===2) c_HourMinut = -1 // tommorrow case ??

  if (myform.time_selector.value) // clear radio button time_selector selection
    document.querySelector('input[name="time_selector"]:checked').checked = false;

  timSelects_Rbuttons.forEach( rButton =>
    { 
    let 
      [o_hour, o_minutes ] = rButton.value.split(':').map(Number)
    , o_HourMinut          = (o_hour *60 ) + o_minutes
    , timOff               = (o_HourMinut < c_HourMinut)
      ;
    rButton.disabled = timOff
    rButton.closest('label').classList.toggle('no-drop',timOff)
    })
  }


//  testing part
myform.onsubmit = e => 
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit for testing

  console.clear()
  console.log('myform.time_selector.value =', myform.time_selector.value )
  }
```

```css
.no-drop { color : orange }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="my-form">

  <div class="tab">
    <div class="row new-rcb ">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
        <h5>Time</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 text-center mb-2">
        <h3>Midday</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="11:00"> 11:00 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="11:15"> 11:15 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="11:30"> 11:30 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="11:45"> 11:45 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="12:00"> 12:00 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="12:15"> 12:15 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="12:30"> 12:30 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="12:45"> 12:45 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="13:00"> 13:00 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="13:15"> 13:15 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="13:30"> 13:30 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="13:45"> 13:45 </label> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row new-rcb ">
      <div class="col-12 text-center mb-2 mt-2">
        <h3>Evening</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="19:00"> 19:00 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="19:15"> 19:15 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="19:30"> 19:30 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="19:45"> 19:45 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="20:00"> 20:00 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="20:15"> 20:15 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="20:30"> 20:30 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="20:45"> 20:45 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="21:00"> 21:00 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="21:15"> 21:15 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="21:30"> 21:30 </label> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="time_selector" value="21:45"> 21:45 </label> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br><br><br><button type="submit"> get Selected (for testing) </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't want to get the clicked value.basically I want to disable passed time and enable all other.But here I am click on radio box and getting the value and that's it.

Comment: @Peter  I do not understand your remark. Basically that's what this code already does: turn off time spent and turn on all others. what is missing ?